# Asserting UIImage generated from UIGraphics is all red

Tags: swift, xctest

A while ago I found some code for changing the background color for a UIButton depending on the state. The code looks like that:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControl.State) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: state)     
    }
}
```

Now I would like to know how I can properly test this function. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Call your extension method
- Call `.backgroundImage(for:)` to get a UIImage
- Render the UIImage to a pixel
- Compare the pixel color value